# Probability that a bin already contains a ball of a given colour

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I am new to probability and my professor asked me the following question but i am unsure if my strategy is correct.

Given $n$ balls of each of $n$ different colours ($n^2$ balls in total), we distribute them among $n$ boxes as follows: for each ball, we choose a box at random. If the chosen box already contains a ball of the same colour as the ball we are considering, we throw the current ball away. Otherwise, we put the ball in the box.

Show that the probability that a box contains a ball of a given color is
$$1-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

The best I can think of is to let 
$$
\begin{align}&\mathrm{A=\{the\ bin\ contains\ a\ ball\ of\ a\ given\ color\}}\\
& \mathrm{A_i\sim Bernoulli}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\\
&\mathrm{P(A_i)= \begin{cases}\frac{1}{n}, & \text{if the bin contains a ball of color i}\\1-\frac{1}{n},&\text{else}\end{cases}}\\
&\mathrm{P(A)=1-P(\bar{A})=1-P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i=0\right)=1-\prod_{i=1}^n P(A_i=0)}\\
&\mathrm{P(A)=1-(P(A_i=0))^n=1-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}
\end{align}$$

While this does produce the right answer, I am unsure if my reasoning is correct

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct; but the presentation is not quite right.

---

Let $A$ be the event that some ball of the given colour entered that particular box.

Let $\{A_i\}$ be a sequence of iid Bernoulli events, that the $i$-th ball of that colour tried to enter the box; the rate is $1/n$.

That is that, $\forall n\in\{1,..,n\}~:~\mathsf P(A_i) = \tfrac 1n$.

Thus it follows that we have the probability for some ball of the given colour having entered the box; by evaluating the complementary event.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A) &= 1-\mathsf P \left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i^\complement \right)\\[1ex] &= 1-(1-\mathsf P(A_i))^n \\[1ex] &= 1-\left(1-\frac 1n\right)^n\end{align}$$